# Переход на активити

Tags: java, android

Я использовал

```
intent = new Intent(this, LocationActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_FROM_CODE);
```

чтобы перейти на этот Активити и получать данные. Но мне сейчас нужно сделать по другому, например у первого Активити 2 кнопки (Куда - Откуда), а у второго EditText, так вот мне на втором активити нужно проверить с какой кнопки перешли... То есть если с кнопки куда - то На EditText в hint прописать КУДА, иначе Откуда!

Глупый даже по моему вопрос, но я не знаю!
Как написать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, объявите две константы целочисленные для каждой из кнопок.

```
private static final int BUTTON_1 = 0;
private static final int BUTTON_2 = BUTTON_1 + 1;
```

На второй `Activity` объявите константу, по которой будете идентифицировать `Extra`.

```
private static final String EXTRA_BUTTON = "extra_button";
```

Затем, добавляйте одну из этих констант в `Extra` ваших интентов, в зависимости от того, с какой кнопки переход осуществляется.

```
i.putExtra(Activity2.EXTRA_BUTTON, BUTTON_1);
```

Теперь, в каком-либо из методов жизненного цикла Activity2 выполните метод:

```
switch (getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_BUTTON, 0)) {
    case Activity1.BUTTON_1:
    //do smth 1
    break;
    case Activity1.BUTTON_2:
    //do smth 2
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
```

А внутри соответствующих кейсов реализуйте свою логику с привязкой к конкретной кнопке.

Comment: Ругается на то что getIntExtra(ExtraButton) - String

Comment: @Omuradil ну так там два параметра в сигнатуре, второй - значение по-умолчанию. Я по памяти писал, упустил это, но IDE вам же подсказывает.

Comment: @Omuradil Не стоит обращаться к статическим полям активити из других классов - это верный путь к утечкам памяти. Просто используйте одинаковый локальный ключ для интента в каждой активити.

Comment: @pavlofff окей, можно вынести их в отдельный класс, но хардкодить их я бы не стал. Уж слишком часто сталкивался с тем, что нужно было внести коррективы в действительно огромном количестве мест.

Answer (score 5):

При нажатии кнопки куда:

```
intent.putExtra("myTxt", "Куда");
```

При нажатии кнопки откуда:

```
intent.putExtra("myTxt", "Откуда");
```

Во втором активити получайте:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("myTxt");
```

и выводите куда вам надо.

Comment: то есть проверка не нужна да?

Comment: нет необходимости делать проверки, так как вы не можете нажать на обе кнопки, intent будет всегда хранить строку той кнопки на которую вы нажали перед стартом новой активити  и это логично.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei так-то оно так, вы правы, но вариант получился очень уж нерасширяемым. Если вдруг логика потом выйдет за пределы "просто хинт прописать", то придётся впиливать проверку уже тогда.

Comment: да, абсолютно верно. Пытаюсь дать ответ на уровне вопроса.